# Capture regex with grep in one line

Tags: regex, bash, grep

In bash, the output of `sensors` on my computer is the following:

```
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +67.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +65.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +65.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +65.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +67.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I need to capture, **in one line, in bash**, the temperature right after Physical id 0, with its unit.

So here, I would like the command to return exactly `67.0°C`.

I tried to chain `grep` commands, here is my attempt

```
sensors | grep -oEi "id[^C]+C" | grep -oEi "[\d.]+°C"
```

Because grouping doesn't seem to be possible with grep, the first group was meant to capture `id 0:  +67.0°C`, and the second one `67.0°C`.

However, nothing is returned. The first grep seems to have returned what it was supposed to, though.

So how to capture this string ? 
Any other technique would be okay, if it is one line in bash.

Comment: Try `sensors | grep -oP 'Physical\s+id\s+\d+:\s+\K[0-9+.]+°C'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With awk:

```
sensors | awk '/^Physical id 0:/ {print $4}'
```

Output:

```
+67.0°C
```

Comment: I think this solution is the more elegant. Or at least more than mine. Upvoting.

Comment: Please add explanation to the answer.

Comment: This is pretty simple! need an explanation? it filters to the the correct line and then print the fourth column.

Comment: If a line starts (`^`) with string `Physical id 0:` print content of column 4.

Comment: You mean that the `/^Physical id 0:/` regex is executed first, and then the matched line gets split with whitespaces and the 4th chunk is then returned?

Comment: awk uses tab and white space by default as column separator.

Comment: I know that bit, I just wonder *how* this solution works. Whether it does column splitting during the regex execution, or as a later step.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: A stand-alone pattern regex such as `/^Physical id 0:/` is the same as `$0 ~ /^Physical id 0:/`; i.e., it is implicitly matched against the _entire input line (record)_, independently of how that line (record) is split into fields.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
s='Physical id 0:  +67.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)'
echo $s | grep '^Physical id 0:' | awk '{print $4}'
```

See the [*online demo*](http://ideone.com/fNzSNt).

Here, `grep '^Physical id 0:'` gets the line that starts with `Physical id 0:` substring (note that `^` is a start-of-line anchor in regex) and then `awk` prints Column 4 (since `awk` splits the lines into columns using tabs and spaces).

This  approach exploits the fact that your string is well structured and there is always the temperature in Celsius after `Physical id 0:`.

If you need better precision, and have access to a GNU `grep`, you may use a PCRE `grep` option `P` to use a PCRE pattern like

```
sensors | grep -oP 'Physical\s+id\s+\d+:\s+\K[0-9+.]+°C'
```

to get 1+ digits, `+` or `.` symbols followed with `°C`.

**Details**:

- `Physical` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `id\s+` - `id` and 1+ whitespaces
- `\d+`  - 1+ digits
- `:` - a colon
- `\s+` -  1 or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `[0-9+.]+` - 1 or more chars that are either digits, `+`, or `.`
- `°C`  - literal `°C` text

Comment: Is match reset operator only available for perl regexes?

Comment: @Lovy: Yes and in Ruby, too. It means you cannot use this solution in Mac OS `grep` that has no `-P` option support. It will work with GNU `grep`.

Comment: @Lovy: If you do not care of what characters appear after `id 0:`, the `[0-9+.]+°C` can be replaced with `\S+`, and it actually means you may use the awk solution suggested by Cyrus.

Comment: well, any advantages to use awk over grep here? Except not having to deal with regexes?

Comment: @Lovy: No idea. I have been using Ubuntu for a short time (so, using GNU `grep` all the time), and had no issues with `grep` with `-P` (I am more accustomed to PCRE regex syntax). I just know there is a performance difference when you use simple patterns with `-E` (POSIX ERE) and `-P` options (PCRE is slower).

Comment: @Lovy the advantages of the `awk` solution are that it's more portable and easier to understand.

Comment: I added another option, also based on `awk` that is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash. First the "large" way to understand it better and then the "oneliner" style.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regex=".*id 0:[ \t]+[\+\-]([0-9\.]+°C).*"
line_filter="Physical id 0"

[[ $(sensors | grep "${line_filter}") =~ ${regex} ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

echo "${result}"
```

If you don't set vars and put the values directly, can be done only in one line. This is the "oneliner" style:

```
[[ $(sensors | grep "Physical id 0") =~ .*id 0:[ \t]+[\+\-]([0-9\.]+°C).* ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

I improved the regex to work with spaces or tab characters because I didn't be sure about what of both can be. Another little improvement I did is the plus "+" symbol. It can be a minus "-" symbol too. Maybe if the temperature is under zero you'll need it :)

Comment: or `sensors | while IFS=":(" read a b c; do [[ $a == "Physical id 0" ]] && echo "${b// /}"; done`

Comment: But this solution takes the plus symbol too... and the OP doesn't want it. I prefer your awk solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

A **POSIX-compliant `sed` solution**, using a BRE (*basic* regular expression):

```
$ sensors | sed -n 's/^Physical id 0:  +\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
67.0°
```

Using modern ERE (*extended* regular expression) syntax with the nonstandard `-E` option - **works with both GNU `sed` and BSD/macOS `sed`**:

```
$ sensors | sed -E -n 's/^Physical id 0:  \+([^ ]*).*/\1/p'
67.0°
```

Note how `(` and `)` need `\`-escaping in BREs in order to have syntactic function, as `+` would, so using just `+` implies *literal* use.

Conversely, in EREs `(` and `)` are metacharacters as-is, as `+` would be, which is why it needs `\`-escaping for *literal* use.

---

As for **what you tried**:

**The only problem (leaving efficiency aside) was that you tried to use `\d`**:

- GNU `grep` doesn't support `\d` to represent a digit at all.
- BSD/macOS `grep` doesn't support it *inside a character set (bracket expression*) (`[...]`).

Using `0-9` in lieu of `\d` would have worked:

```
$ sensor | grep -oEi "id[^C]+C" | grep -oEi '[0-9.]+°C'
67.0°C
```

If use of `-P` is not an option (*GNU* `grep` only, which enables a single-pass solution - see [Wiktor Stribiżew's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044695/45375)), **a simpler two-pass solution** is:

```
$ sensor | grep -oEi "id[^C]+C" | cut -d'+' -f2
67.0°C
```